# PHP script to permanently post HTML input text to a list

Tags: php, html, forms, list, input

```html
<form action="cv_input.php">
    education<br>
    <input type="text" name="degree" value="degree">
    <input type="text" name="institution" value="institution">
    <input type="text" name="year" value="year"><br><br>
    selected exhibition<br>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="title">
    <input type="text" name="venue" value="venue">
    <input type="text" name="year" value="year"><br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I want to take the data entered into this form and use `cv_input.php` to print the data permanently to a list of text on the same page. Would `$variable = $_GET["name_of_input"]` work?

Comment: I guess you can use JavaScript or jQuery for that, no need for php  here.

Comment: "Would ... work?" Why don't you try it?

Comment: @connor do you need to save the form on the server or just print it on the page ?

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard because I was posting from class on a campus where port 22 is closed and I can't remotely access the code on my server.

Answer (score 0):

I asked you:

> @connor do you need to save the form on the server or just print it on
>   the page ?

The following code assume that you **just need the form values printed on the pa**ge.
If you need to post the form to a server, please leave a comment below.

---

My solution is with `jQuery`:

```
<form id="cvinput">
    education<br>
    <input type="text" name="degree" value="degree">
    <input type="text" name="institution" value="institution">
    <input type="text" name="year" value="year"><br>
  <br>selected exhibition<br>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="title">
    <input type="text" name="venue" value="venue">
    <input type="text" name="year" value="year"><br><br>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
<div id="result"> </div>


<script>
$("#cvinput").submit(function(event) {
  $("#result").html("");
  $('#cvinput input').each(function(index) {
    var input = $(this);
    $("#result").append('Name: ' + input.attr('name') + '  Value: ' + input.val() + '<br />');
   console.log('Name: ' + input.attr('name') + '  Value: ' + input.val());
 })
return false;
});
</script>
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/NqKJdr)